GoogleGenerativeAIError: Error embedding content - Using LlamaIndex
I am trying to use GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings from llamaindex for creating the embeddings, but from past two days it is giving the error as: GoogleGenerativeAIError: Error embedding content: MessageToDict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'including_default_value_fields'
It was working till last week but now I am getting this error. How can I solve this?
I also tried to replace API key with the newly created one, but still issue remains the same.
